# Two independent probability density functions X>Y

Tags: probability

There are two light bulbs.

Lifetime of X : $f(x) = {1\over100}e^{-x/100}, x>0$
Lifetime of Y : $f(y) = {1\over50}e^{-y/50}, y>0$

f(x) and f(y) are independent.

What is the probability of X lasts longer than Y?

I think it is $\int_y^\infty{f(x)dx}$ but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** One usually computes
$$\Pr(Y<X) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \Pr(Y<x)f_X(x)\;dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} F_Y(x)f_X(x)\;dx$$

Now use your known CDFs/PDFs.

The idea is that it's hard to deal with more than one RV at a time. So, intuitively speaking, we fix the value of one of them, and "add up" (= integrate) all the possibilities, weighted by the density (roughly, the probability that the fixed value gets assumed) to get the "total" probability.